# Create an object ArrayList from a class

Tags: c#, c++, object, arraylist, visual-studio-2005

I want to know if is possible in Visual Studio 2005 C++ to create an ArrayList of objects of a class.

I will have this class:

```
class var
{
   int x;
   int y;
}
```

In C# is something like this: `ArrayList<var> list = new ArrayList<var>();` , but in C++ doesn't work.

I forgot to mention that the project is a **Windows Form Application**.

Comment: Do you mean `std::vector`?

Comment: Offtopic: Does `var` is a valid variable name in VS2005 C++?

Comment: Maybe, the name class will not be that, i just put an example

Comment: FSou1, he defined class "var" of his own ;)

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried `std::vector<var> myVector` or `std::list<var> myList`?

Comment: `std::list` is probably not what is wanted. It's quite different, and `std::vector` is the one that should be used unless it's proven you need otherwise.

Comment: @chris I'm aware that `std::list` is quite different than `std::vector`, but I just wanted to point out the possibilities of having a collection of var typed objects.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the project is a Windows Form Application and I have errors with std, I need to use a namespace or a library ?

Comment: you have to go with `#include <vector>` and `using namespace std;`

Comment: Works now, but now how I can add a var object in vector and how I can display her ?

Comment: See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/ as it will explain thoroughly :).

Answer (score 2):

That should do the job:

```
#include <vector>

using std::vector;

class var
{
   int x;
   int y;
};

int main(void)
{
    vector<var> myVec(10); // creates a vector of 10 elements of var objects

    // ... other stuff

    return 0;
}
```

But there are many more ways to put objects into a vector, e.g. create an empty vector and using `vector::push_back()`, etc. You should read the Standard libs' documentation for all the alternatives.

Comment: Why not array of objects instead, why use a vector>

Comment: I forgot to mention that the project is a Windows Form Application, and I don't find the namespace std.

Comment: @Subhajit As I pointed out in my last paragraph: There are many more solutions to that. Using a simple array limits you to a fixed size during runtime and to the stack. If this is sufficient, it can be used. But as soon as the array size needs to be dynamic or the size of the total data would exceed the stack space, vector or one of its' relatives is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
var myArray[50];
```

Which are 50 vars on the stack. You can also do this:

```
var* myArray = new var[50];
```

Which are 50 vars on the heap. Or you could just use a std::vector:

```
var myObject;
std::vector <var> myVector;
myVector.push_back(var);
```

Or, the last one that I usually use is:

```
std::vector <var*> myVector;
var* pVar = new var();
myVector.push_back(pVar);
```

There are way too many ways of doing it, these are just a few.

Comment: Needlessly using a vector of pointers is rather *point*less. Now you have to worry about cleaning it up.

Comment: `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>>`. No more cleaning up or worrying about exceptions.

Comment: I use the last one and works, but now how I can add a var object in vector and how I can display her ?

Comment: I edited my answer, which shows how to add a pointer to an object. Then to access it, its the same as you normally would with a vector but you use -> instead of . because its a pointer.

Comment: For example, you could technically say myVector[0]->x = 5; provided that myVector[0] is a valid pointer.